# Chat is now available

Tags: discussion, chat

It looks like chat has been turned on for BCGSE now. This gives us another, more casual place to discuss anything related to boardgames or the site. There appear to be two rooms that have been created linked to BCGSE, but I'd recommend using the ["Board and Card Games"](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49/board-and-card-games) room for the least confusion.

So stop on by and say "hi". Good topics for discussion might be how to help grow the site, migrating any long comment threads that might better be handled in chat than in comments, or anything else that we need to do that's more discussion oriented than Q&A oriented.

Any suggestions for other good uses of chat?

Comment: Maybe it's just Firefox, but I'm getting a "The page isn't redirecting properly" error when clicking on the link

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables I am too, now, in both Safari and Chrome. I was just about to report this on meta.so, and now that you've confirmed it, I'm less worried that it's just me.

Comment: Oh, there's already a thread about the problem: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69169/cant-access-chat-se-multiple-browsers-deliver-a-too-many-redirects-browser-er

Comment: Yeah, I didn't see it either... it didn't seem immediately related, but oh well, at least they're aware of it.